# Block Jenkins pipeline build when another particular job is running

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am converting a Jenkins Freestyle build to a pure pipeline based job.
Current configuration uses https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-blocker-plugin/ as shown in the image.
[image]

How can I use it in a Declarative pipeline?

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'docker-u20' }
    
    //Don't run until the "test-job" running
    blockon("test-job")

    stage{}

}
```

I did try to look into various jenkins docs but haven't found yet.

Comment: Isn't there a syntax generator on the LH side menu?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are using a blocking plugin? I did something similar but using just groovy code, if you are interested in such a solution, I can post it in the answer